# Error 1004 in Cells funcion when the columnindex is using a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

This does not work

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim column1 As String
    Dim row As String
    Dim cell As Object
    column1 = 2 'ActiveCell.column
    row = 2
    Set cell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Item(row, column1)
    cell.Select
    ' MsgBox ActiveCell.column
    ' ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Select
    
End Sub
```

If I use

```
Set cell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Item(row, column1)
```

It works fine

Comment: Any reason you're declaring your _numeric_ variables as `String`? Use `Dim column1 As Integer` and `Dim row As Integer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Long instead of string

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim column1 As Long
    Dim row As Long
    Dim cell As Object
    column1 = 2 'ActiveCell.column
    row = 2
    Set cell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Item(row, column1)
    cell.Select
    ' MsgBox ActiveCell.column
    ' ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Select
    
End Sub
```